# React Redux - changes aren't reflected in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I created a simple React component for generating menu, and I wanted to replace it's visibility toggling with Redux (instead of state).

My component looks like this:

```
class SiteMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  toggle(force = false) {
    let active = !active;

    store.dispatch({
      type: 'TOGGLE',
      active
    });
  }

  render() {
    const wrapperClass = this.props.active ? `${this.props.className}__wrapper ${this.props.className}__wrapper--active` : `${this.props.className}__wrapper`;
    return (
      <nav className={this.props.className} ref="nav">
        <button className={`${this.props.className}__trigger`} onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}>
          {this.props.active}
        </button>
        <ul className={wrapperClass}>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

I added `mapStateToProps`:

```
const mapStateToProps = (store) => {
  return {
    active: store.menuState.active
  }
};
```

and `connect`

```
connect(mapStateToProps)(SiteMenu);
```

My store:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers/index.js';

const store = createStore(reducers, window.devToolsExtension && window.devToolsExtension());
export default store;
```

and reducers:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import menuReducer from './menu-reducer';

const reducers = combineReducers({
  menuState: menuReducer
});

export default reducers;
```

---

```
const initialMenuState = {
  active: false
};

const menuReducer = (state = initialMenuState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'TOGGLE':
      console.log(action);
      return Object.assign({}, state, { active: action.active });
  }

  return state;
};

export default menuReducer;
```

When I check my Redux DevTools, state is changing. What should I do?

Code in the repo: https://github.com/tomekbuszewski/react-redux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to use connect func , also you should add Provider from react-redux

```
render(<Provider store={store}><Parent /></Provider>, app);
```

then you should add wrapped component to Parent component

```
const SiteMenuWrapped = connect(mapStateToProps)(SiteMenu);

///in Parent component
<Header className="site-header">
      <SiteMenuWrapped 
        className="site-navigation"
        content={this.state.sections}
      />
</Header>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works ;-) I don't understand why I need a wrapper though.

Comment: because "connect "  is connecting to store. otherwise you cant access mapStateToProps. and you don't get data from store

Comment: btw , you don't need "wrapped" in component name

Comment: I figured that out ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Few issues:

1. `connect` returns a higher order component, so best advice is to split out each component to a separate file and export the result of `connect`. See the examples at e.g. http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html. This means that your `mapStateToProps` function is never being called, hence why `this.props.active` is always undefined.
2. Your store registration is incorrect, the second parameter to `createStore` is the initial state. To register the Chrome Redux dev tools see https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension
3. You should use `<Provider>` to make the store available to all components. See the Redux docs.
4. You can dispatch actions through `this.props.dispatch` or use `mapDispatchToProps`, see https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md

Comment: Actually, it is changing from `true` to `false` when I watch the DevTools. But, my problem is that the change is not reflected in my component. I have this code: `const wrapperClass = this.props.active ? `${this.props.className}__wrapper ${this.props.className}__wrapper--active` : `${this.props.className}__wrapper`;
` and it always is `false`, even if DevTools says that it should be `true`.

Comment: Are you saying the value of `wrapperClass` is still `__wrapper` instead of `__wrapper--active` because `this.props.active` is always false?

Comment: It is `__wrapper`, always. But logging in the console `this.props` returns only the props I have put there by hand. When I did add `active` prop, it didn't change aswell.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I haven't seen this Redux examples you posted, I'll get through them soon ;-)