# React-Redux component does not reflect changes in Redux Store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to Redux and i've been having a hard time rendering changes made to the store. I've been using Redux-DevTools to explore state changes and here is my problem.

I have a sidebar which has expanded state as true/false. Initial state is below.

```
{expanded: false}
```

During the toggle action i trigger store.dispatch to change the state to true.
In React-DevTools i could see that my state is being changed, the console also logs the change when executed from within my sidenav component.

I have a home page which is able to fetch the initial state of the store, however the actions from sidenav which updates the store doesn't re-render(props val dint change) the home page.

I strongly feel the issue is related to this SO post but not able to get around the wrapped component concept. Any advice.

[React Redux - changes aren't reflected in component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144817/react-redux-changes-arent-reflected-in-component?rq=1)

Below is code.

[image: Edit p52155my9j]

> Redux Store

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    sideBarReducerMain: sidebarReducer })

export const configurestore = () => {
    const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(
      ));

    return store; }
```

> Action generators

```
export const onExpand = {
    type: 'EXPAND',
    payload: {
        expanded: true
    }
}

export const onCollapse = {
    type: 'COLLAPSE',
    payload: {
        expanded: false
    }
}
```

> Reducer

```
export const sidebarReducer = (state = {expanded:false},action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
     case 'EXPAND':
        return Object.assign({}, state, {expanded: true})
     case 'COLLAPSE':
        return Object.assign({}, state, {expanded: false})
    default:
        return state;   
 }
}
```

> SideBar Toggle (The console logs the new state on every toggle)

```
onToggle = (expanded) => {

    expanded ? store.dispatch(onExpand):store.dispatch(onCollapse)
    this.setState({ expanded: expanded });

    //outputs the state change looks fine.
    console.log("State of store :: " + store.getState());

};
```

> Home page

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Main from './MainAlign'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class HomePage extends React.Component {


 getExpansionState() {
  console.log("From render" + this.props.expandedState)
    return this.props.expandedState
 }

 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  console.log("Looks like this never gets called :( " + this.props.expandedState)
}


  render(props) {

      return (
        <div>
        <Main expanded={this.getExpansionState()}>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <p>This is my site. Take a look around!</p>
        </Main>  
        </div>
      )


  }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log("New state " + state.expanded)
  return {
    expandedState: state.expanded
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomePage);
```

> REDUX DevTools

[image: ReduxDevTools]

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(this.props.expandedState)` after your render but before your return in your HomePage component?

Comment: The value is undefined

Comment: In `mapStateToProps` you are not accessing the name of the reducer. It should be `state.sideBarRedycerMain.expended`

Comment: Thanks Sagiv i fixed that also ensure that redux state is not mutated, the problem still exists :( . I could be missing bind action, but the action is actually from the side nav component which updates the state.

Comment: I’ve updated sandbox in question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare [action creators](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions#action-creators) (functions) which return actions (objects):

```
export const onExpand = () => ({
  type: "EXPAND",
  payload: {
    expanded: true
  }
});
```

Then instead of calling `store.dispatch`, you should connect the action creator:

```
withRouter(connect(null, { onExpand, onCollapse })(SideBar))
```

And invoke it in your component:

```
if (expanded) {
  this.props.onExpand();
} else {
  this.props.onCollapse();
}
```

Working code:

[image: Edit xj64o1j0kw]

#### Misc

```
this.setState({ expanded: expanded });
console.log("FROM SIDENAV" + this.state.expanded);
```

`setState` is asynchronous so you need use the callback to access the updated value:

```
this.setState({ expanded }, () => console.log("FROM SIDENAV" + this.state.expanded));
```

Also, there's no need to replicate the redux state in local component (single source of truth).

You can also combine `onExpand` and `onCollapse` into a single `onToggle` function and perform the toggle in reducer: `expanded: !state.expanded`, or pass the `expanded` flag as payload.

Comment: I can't believe I missed the function part of the action creators :) Nice answer with the other explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Change your mapStateToProps function like that:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log("New state " + state.expanded)
  return {
    expandedState: state.sideBarReducerMain.expanded
  }
}
```

You have a sideBarReducerMain state in your root,global state. This sideBarRecuerMain state has an expanded value not the global one.

Also, you don't need a payload for your action creators since you don't use them. Just a type is enough for your logic.

Comment: Now the initial value of the new state is false as expected, however still the prop is not available when i toggle
The value is false

Comment: Do you see the `expanded` state in your Home component right now or not?

Comment: Yeah the first time it renders the expandedState has the value false which gets logged, but when i toggle the sidebar the state changes to true > false > true
this action from sidebarcomponent doesnt reflect in the home page

Comment: is the problem related to wrapped components, i could figure out how it can be used in this scenario 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144817/react-redux-changes-arent-reflected-in-component?rq=1

Comment: Oh, don't you have Provider on the root of your component?

Comment: Yeah I have a provider on the root approuter

Comment: Can you put your code somewhere else like codesandbox? Not tonight anymore but maybe tomorrow I will look at it. Also, not only me maybe other people want to see the other part of your code.